# Wordpress change upload path after moving the site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

So, I had a wordpress site, which was in `site.com/dev` and now I moved to the root `site.com` and changed the siteurl, but the images are still pointing to `site.com/dev` any solution to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress embeds full/absolute urls in everything it saves to the database. Moving the database to a different domain/path structure will break all those links. Read [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) on how to fix it